# Build Bundle(s) / Apk(s) disabled

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build a signed release APK but Build Bundle(s) / Apk(s) is grey.
I've tryed with several project, also also reinstalled Flutter & Android Studio.
Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I have the same problem - and it's been holding me up for some time.  If you have any info or pointers, they would be gratefully welcomed!

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it from within Android Studio. You need to run `flutter build apk` in a terminal from within the project directory. Then you will find the apk in the `build/app/outputs/apk/` directory. To have the apk be signed is a bit more difficult. For that, you'll need to setup apk signing from within the app level build.gradle. There are some good guides out there on how to do this. I'll link to one if I come across it again.

The [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app) website has a guide on how to do it. For security reasons, you should load the keystore credentials from a `key.properties` file and add it to your `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 3):

"Build Bundle(s) / Apk(s)" option is greyed out when you are viewing it from Project View on the navigation. You need to change to Android View. And to do that you go to Tools --> Flutter --> Open Android module in Android Studio.

You might need to restart android studio if files are not showing under Android view.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you are coming from 2023, THIS is the way. The flutter clean at the top did not do anything at all. The idea for using flutter build apk works but then you got the signing problem, so that also does not work for testing or publishing in the store. This answer was the only one that helped me continue with the development process.

Comment: This worked for me in 2024.

Answer (score 2):

Tools>Flutter>Flutter Clean

after it Build Bundle(s)/Apk(s) button became active again

Answer (score 1):

It should work. But before you have to understood now main function run in chrome or any device run.

If you need android apk build go to

Tools-->[image]

Open an android module in android studio.

It will open another project in android studio. Then try it should work